# Testing DAO and Service layer with in-memory db and mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking

During my learning of testing in Java, I faced a thing which I didn't really get.
So, basically, I have unit tests for DAO where I test CRUD operations with the help of in-memory database HSQL.
Well, the next step is to test the Service layer. On the web, they say to use mocks to mock DAO and then test Service.

I see only one way to use mocks: if there are some methods in Service and those methods don't exist in DAO. Then, we don't need to test CRUD operation(DAO itself), therefore we mock DAO and test only Service.

1. But what If I have the same methods in Service as in DAO?
2. And what If I just use an in-memory database to test Service as I did with DAO?

**I'd like to know** what are the benefits to use **mocks** instead of an **in-memory database**. Moreover, I guess, it is less readable when use Mocks.

*If it makes any sense - I use Spring.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from experience (of having written thousands of automated tests):

1. Avoid mocking as much as possible, as it's not conducive to good, proper tests. Usually, tests that use mocking are written from the wrong point of view, where the developer thinks only of executing the implementation code, rather than checking meaningful business-oriented behavior. Good tests are written from *requirements*, not merely to exercise code.
2. Integration tests can be fast enough (what really matters is that developers don't get discouraged from running them often), and they can be made to run in rollback-only DB transactions, therefore ensuring test isolation.
3. Use your development database (usually a shared remote db using the same db engine as in production, where the application can be manually tested as well) rather than an in-memory db. This way, you avoid the expensive in-memory db schema creation on every test run (assuming the dev db is always up and running, with all tables, which is normally the case), and any potential issues caused by using two different db technologies.

The above describes the approach I use in Java web applications (using Java EE or Spring, doesn't matter) having hundreds of tables in a relational db (accessed with JPA/Hibernate). There is only one test suite of *out-of-container* integration tests, where each test runs in a single db transaction which is always rolled back. Some tests do a bit of mocking, in particular for calls to remote web services, but that's it.

Comment: So basically, it is not a good practice to mock dao when you test service, right? To my opinion if you test service you don't really want to use your real dao. You may have already unit test for dao. Due to your experience you recommend to use development database whether it's dao or service?

Comment: And in addition, what if I want to test my controllers in Spring MVC then how can I test them without mocking? So far, I've seen method to test them with Spring’s MvcMock which is mocking, obviously

Comment: Regarding number 3, I've always found these types of tests to be very brittle, especially on any team with more than a few people, because you then have to worry about people stomping on your data, or having to very carefully craft the test data.  How do you handle these situations?

Comment: Mocking DAOs is a bad idea. Spring's `MockMvc` is not "mocking" in the conventional sense, as it merely simulates an HTTP request being sent to an MVC controller.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong For me, they haven't been brittle, on the contrary. There is no "other people stomping on your data" because of the automatic transaction rollback; except where shared data that's already in the DEV db gets used in a test, then it occasionally may happen, which indicates the test needs to be changed to set up the data itself (which we do through helper data creation classes). Usually, it's tests that use mocking that tend to be brittle, since they are inherently more coupled to the implementation of the classes being tested.

Comment: @Rogério Thanks for the insights. The stomping I was referring to how to handle situations where you have shared data. In my experience, that was a common occurrence because it was a fairly large team and it relied on agreements to prevent it from happening. Did you have situations where you had to have multiple transactions within a service or were you able to avoid those situations?

Comment: @JasonArmstrong I probably haven't had to handle a test having multiple db transactions. If needed, it could be handled through mocking of the explicit "commit" calls.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad and potentially contentious topic…so be prepared for a wide variety of answers and divergent view points…

The advantage of in-memory databases:

- ***Might*** reduce one set of integration tests that are designed to ensure that you’re avoiding lazy/explicit loading cases and that you’re getting properly formatted entities back.
- In some cases it ***might*** reduce the setup code required in each of your test methods.  e.g. if you have to set up a dozen mock calls on a few different mocks.
- Can sometimes be easier to reason about the test when understanding what is being tested

Disadvantages of in memory databases:

- Lacks full isolation for your unit tests
- Requires your DI container to be initialized for unit tests.
- May provide false sense of security depending on how different the in-memory database provider is from your production database,

The advantage of mocks:

- Fully isolate code under test
- Can set up just what is needed to support your tests.  e.g. don't need full and complete entities configured.
- Tests often run faster and you can completely ignore your DI framework for the unit testing (part of isolation but worth mentioning).

Disadvantages of mocks:

- Test code may become complex and brittle depending on how cohesive the service methods are, and how they are coupled to the DAO layer.  i.e. if you need to set up 20 mock method invocation and three mock objects, that quickly becomes tedious (however, that should be a sign that your service needs to be refactored).

To answer the first question you asked about what happens when you have the same method in both -- easy answer.  They aren't the same method.  They're doing two different things.  One's communicating with the database, the other is applying business logic.  If you do have a pass through, you should still probably throw a test on it in the service layer too, to make sure it's calling the right thing on your DAO.

No matter which way you go, don't forget to also integration test your code!